# Type error in basic maths operation

Tags: python, typeerror

```
def dingle_plot(file,T):
    #make an array of the fields you want to have
    #invB=[]
    sdhx, main_sig=eff(file)
    rho_0=main_sig[sdhx.index(min(sdhx, key=lambda x:abs(x-0.)))]
    maxx, maxy, minx, miny=maxmin(sdhx, main_sig)
    maxfitx, maxfity=fit(maxx,maxy, 0.3,1.001, 0.001)
    minfitx, minfity=fit(minx,miny, 0.3,1.001, 0.001)
    delta_rho_rho_0=[]
    delta_rho_rho_0=dingle_dif(maxfitx, maxfity, minfitx, minfity,sdhx,delta_rho_rho_0)/rho_0
    sdhx=np.array(sdhx)
    invB= 1./sdhx
    print invB
    etha=(2*(np.pi)**2*kb*T*effm)/(hbar*e)
    y= delta_rho_rho_0*(np.sinh(etha)/etha)
    pylab.plot(invB,y)
```

When I call this function it gives an error saying:

```
 File "C:/Users/crosshat/Documents/SiGe/Sample Thomas/effective mass.py", line 228, in <module>
    dingle_plot(c,0.648)

  File "C:/Users/crosshat/Documents/SiGe/Sample Thomas/effective mass.py", line 210, in dingle_plot
    etha=(2*(np.pi)**2*kb*T*effm)/(hbar*e)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'file'
```

What is the error here?

Comment: The error is, that you're trying to multiply a `float` and a `file`. Your job now is to identify which multiplication that is. Try simplifying the expression.

Comment: What is `hbar` and what is `e` ? We are missing some information here.

Comment: A cheap way to debug this is to add `print locals()` just before the offending line.

Comment: well the file itself is a list of float...so I fixed the above error by passing an argument for T. Now it gives the next error as-

  File "C:\Users\crosshat\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack.py", line 455, in splrep
    raise TypeError('m > k must hold')

TypeError: m > k must hold

@Maxime- hbar and e are the reduced plancks constant and charge of an electron

Comment: How do I fix the m>k error in the fit

Comment: Where in _your_ code does this error come from?  What are _m_ and _k_ here?